# Rails: Active Query, Getting the last items of all objects (in bulk) in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby, activerecord, psql

I've searched for the answer for quite some time now. Probably a total of 30 hours of intermittent searching as the need arises, but I've always failed in finding the answer that yield the desired results. So I've decided to ask the question here in SO instead of adding more hours to the search.

Let me put out the models in code to help better your knowledge of the scenario.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee_locations
  has_many :countries, through: employee_locations
end

class EmployeeLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  has_one    :country
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee_location
end
```

If I want to display a list in bulk (@employees) wherein all the Employees and all other details connected to each employee (Employee Name, Employee Location (which is the Country's name)). And, I wanted it ordered by the country.name where the employee is located by the latest employee_location record, how should I go about this in code? (has ransack)

The closest one (despite hours of searching) is

```
@employees = Employee.includes(:countries).order('countries.name asc').ransack(params[:put_any]).result
```

However, it unfortunately uses the first employee_locations item for the employee object instead of the last.

I'm totally clueless on how to go move forward from thereon as all SO questions/answers I've visited are unsatisfactory. Therefore, I'm asking the question on how to get the last items of all objects in a has_many relationship (all the last employee_locations for all employee objects), hopefully without making it into an array.

Remember that the employee has_many employee_locations.

I want to stress that this has to be in bulk (@employees), not one-by-one (@employee), as there are more than 50,000 records associated to the system, and therefore, will be slowed down by such code.

Edit:
Just to help you with the intended scenario / result.

```
Employees = A, B, C, D, E
Location = 1, 2, 3

The following locations are entered into the system in order
Employee A locations = 1, 2
Employee B locations = 2, 3
Employee C locations = 3, 1
Employee D locations = 2, 1
Employee E locations = 1, 3

The list should display:
Name       | Location
Employee C | Location 1
Employee D | Location 1
Employee A | Location 2
Employee B | Location 3
Employee E | Location 3

Previous attempts are displaying:
Name       | Location
Employee A | Location 2
Employee E | Location 3
Employee B | Location 3
Employee D | Location 1
Employee C | Location 1
```

Comment: Can you post the schema? Check your model: `Country has_one :country`?

Comment: what do you mean by "display a list" ? ActiveRecord provides ways to build a relation. Assuming we can query the data correctly, what do you want to do with an object which may contain 50k records? where would you "display" it?

Comment: My apologies. I would display the list in table format, wherein the table headers are 1) Employee Name, 2) Location Name (current country the employee is residing in) (the real site has a lot more (e.g. salary, etc.) but the data I specified are what I deemed important for the question. @lacostenycoder

Comment: Ah it's not supposed to be that way, it's a writing error on my end. Will edit it for future readers. The schema I have has a lot of models and other fields of the specified models that are irrelevant to the question. Also, I would still need to leave them behind for confidentiality purposes. My apologies. @iGian

Comment: @MikoUyDagatan, I understand.Why not to add `belongs_to :employee_location` to `Country`?

Comment: @iGian My apologies again, it's supposed to be belongs_to :employee_location on Country since Employee already has many :countries, through: :employee_locations. Writing error.

Comment: @MikoUyDagatan Did you try to also sort `employee_locations` by `created_at`? `.order('countries.name asc and employee_locations.created_at desc')`. You might need to add `references(:employee_locations)` at the end of AR query

Comment: @MartinZinovsky hi Martin. Order didn't work with 'and'. I had it changed to a comma. I added the references(:employee_locations) at the end of the code. With all that was suggested, it still didn't produce the desired result (It's still the same with my previous attempts). It didn't get ordered based on the last :employee_location data per :employee. It used the first :employee_location per :employee in doing the ordering.